# count how many times an attribute is repeated, using "field calculator"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

I'm using Arcgis 10.2.2 
there is a way to count how many times an attribute is repeated, using the "field calculator"

to make a selection after example of repeating more than 20 times

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Summary Statistics (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000) using the COUNT option on your field, then from that, you can see which repeat "more than 20 times" or however many times.